# Which screen resolution should I target for modern mobile phones?

Tags: web-development, website-design, mobile, screen-size, responsive-webdesign

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building for different screen sizes](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14543/building-for-different-screen-sizes)

I am developing a site which needs to work on mobiles as well.

I avoid specifying width and height by pixel. Mostly I am using percent for that but sometimes I need a specific area. for example, 300px `div` element.

Which screen resolution should I target for modern mobile phones in general?

I know it varies but what is the higher number. Most of my concerns are iPhone, Windows Phone and Android.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building for different screen sizes](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14543/building-for-different-screen-sizes) There are also specific answers about resolutions out ther http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20894/mobile-device-screen-resolution-statistics

Comment: I use 320px with 10px margins, that makes 300px view able.

Answer (score 0):

I would say 320px sounds about right for Smartphones, with iPads jumping up to 768px.

Answer (score 0):

For most modern mobile browsers site designs based on a 960 pixel grid will work fine. You may want to allow for a generous margin though, making the effective size about 800 pixels. There are some devices, such as early iPhones, that won't work quite as well at this size but you said you wanted to primarily support modern/current mobile browsers.

Also remember that most people doing mobile browsing will pivot to a landscape orientation when view standard websites. For content heavy sites, you may find more success with tablet users by going with a single column and using a magazine like layout (they love this).

Another key thing to remember is that mobile users love pinch-zoom functionality and dislike dropdown menus and collapsible regions.